# Probability of 10 kids separating into teams A and B

Tags: combinatorics

I know that the sample space is $10 \choose 5$, because we're picking 5 people from 10 to be on each team. However, if there are 5 girls and 5 boys, what is the probability that one team will be girls only? I know that it should be $(1/2)^5$ because we're picking one girl each time, correct? But is there a way to do this with combinatorics?

Comment: The $(1/2)^5$ is not right, since as you pick more and more girls the proportion of girls to pick from decreases. Just note, as you did, that there are $\binom{10}{5}$ equally likely ways to pick Team A, and your desired event can happen in $2$ ways, Team A is all girls and Team A is all boys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the teams are labeled, your sample space is correct.  However, the probability that one of the teams consisting solely of girls is not $(1/2)^5$.

**Hint:**  If the teams are labeled, then there are exactly two ways of picking a team consisting solely of girls.  Either they are on team A, or they are on team B.  Thus, what is the probability of selecting a team that consists solely of girls?

Comment: If there are only 2 ways, then it would just be 1/2? Thus the probability is (1/2) / (10 choose 5)?

Comment: No, the probability is the number of ways the event can occur divided by the number of events in the sample space.

Comment: I'm just confused on how I would pick if a team is either all girls or all boys.  I understand that the probability is the team of all girls divided by the sample space, and I have the sample space, but I have no idea how to get the chance of a team of all girls

Comment: The probability would be $$\frac{2}{\binom{10}{5}}$$ since there are two ways of selecting a team consisting solely of girls and $\binom{10}{5}$ ways of selecting two labeled teams of five people from a group consisting of five boys and five girls.

Comment: -facepalm- Of course. Sorry for being so dumb about this.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\frac{How\ many\ ways\ can\ you\ have\ a\ team\ of\ all\ girls}{How\ many\ ways\ can\ you\ pick\ the\ teams} $$